# Trying to convert MyISAM to InnoDB, result into error

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am trying to convert a very big table to InnDB. But it throws an error.
Here is the screenshot of the issue which came after running for 5 minutes.

[image]

**UPDATE:** This is a live production table where live data are coming. Seems like the auto_increment column is causing the issue. By the time the it applies the InnoDB engine new records are coming and the auto_increment is increased again.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. You cannot copy code or error messages from images, they aren't indexed and they're often hard to read for other people.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind. Please reopen it. The answer you tagged is not the answer for my question. It is something related to auto_increment.

Comment: Did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-table.html about this error? While MySQL does the ALTER TABLE to convert the table, it must store both the MyISAM file and the InnoDB file until it finishes filling the InnoDB file. So there must be plenty of free storage space until it is done, and then it can drop the MyISAM file. I imagine your table just filled up the disk during the ALTER.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check official mysql documentation ? There is one useful text, maybe can help.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Maybe just to try with ALTER TABLE your_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
I mean, without auto increment.